# Vue router event on mounted

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

How can get router params in mounted?

```js
import VueInBrowserLoader from 'vueinbrowserloader'

export default {
  name: 'Page',
  components: {
    'Template': VueInBrowserLoader(`../pages/${this.$route.params.event}.vue`)
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.$route.params`

Comment: not works in mounted ()
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Comment: Show your routes.js please

Comment: export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: {
        name: 'Event',
        params: {
          event: 'battlepass'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/event/:event',
      name: 'Event',
      component: Event
    }
  ],
  mode: 'history',
  base: config.route,
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  linkExactActiveClass: 'exact-active'
})

and in component event I'm trying get the router.event in mounted

Comment: I am not sure but I think it could be because of this `event`. Not sure if it's a reserved word. Try something else and check if it works.